# My induction does not prove my conjecture. Is my conjecture wrong or is my induction insufficient/wrong?

Tags: proof-verification, summation, induction

I am asked to consider the following sequence:
$$1=0+1\\2+3+4=1+8\\5+6+7+8+9=8+27\\10+11+12+13+14+15+16=27+64$$
The questions are:

a) What is the next equality in this sequence?

b) What conjecture is suggested by these equalities?

c) Prove the conjecture in (b) by induction.

Here are my answers:

a) $17+18+19+20+21+22+23+24+25=27+64$

b) $\forall i \in \mathbb{Z}^+, \sum_{k=(i-1)^2+1}^{i^2}k=(i-1)(i-1)^2+(i)^3$

c)  $$\text{Proof: We proceed by induction.} \\\text{Base case: } \sum_{k=(1-1)^2+1}^{1^2}k=1, (1-1)(1-1)^2+(1)^3=0+1=1, \\\text{Thus: } LHS=RHS  \\\text{We assume for some integer z, } \sum_{k=(z-1)^2+1}^{z^2}k=(z-1)(z-1)^2+(z)^3 \\\text{We need to show, } \sum_{k=(z-1)^2+1}^{(z+1)^2}k=(z)^3+(z+1)^3 \\\text{Hence, } \sum_{k=(z-1)^2+1}^{z^2}k + (z+1)^2 = \sum_{k=(z-1)^2+1}^{(z+1)^2}k=(z-1)(z-1)^2+(z)^3+(z+1)^2$$

But from there I can't get:

$$(z-1)(z-1)^2+(z)^3+(z+1)^2=(z)^3+(z+1)^3$$

Maybe I am misunderstanding something here that should be obvious but I am still learning to prove by induction. Using strong induction has gone through my mind but at this point I don't feel confident enough in my understanding of strong induction to use it here. (I am self-learning this.)

---

Update: This is how I proved it by using the index of the summation.

We notice in what we want to show, that if we change the indexing to zero, then we can write the summation as follows:

$$ \text{Let } p\ge 0 \text{.} \\ \sum_{k=(p)^2+1}^{(p+1)^2}k=((p+1)-1)((p+1)-1)^2+(p+1)^3 =  (p)^3+(p+1)^3 \blacksquare$$

Comment: You've assumed it true for $$\sum_{k=(z-1)^2+1}^{z^2}k$$. You should then follow with showing $$\sum_{k=z^2+1}^{(z+1)^2}k$$ which I believe is where your error lies

Comment: If you have two sequences, $\{a_n\},\,\{b_n\}$ and you wish to show they are equal it suffices to show that $a_0=b_0$ and that $a_n-a_{n-1}=b_n-b_{n-1}$.  However, in this case I think a direct method is much easier (see my posted solution).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your approach is correct but you have some minor mistakes in your approach.

For example $$17+18+19+20+21+22+23+24+25=27+64$$ should have been

$$17+18+19+20+21+22+23+24+25=64+125$$

and $$\text{We need to show, } \sum_{k=(z-1)^2+1}^{(z+1)^2}k=(z)^3+(z+1)^3$$

Should have been $$\text{We need to show, } \sum_{k=z^2+1}^{(z+1)^2}k=(z)^3+(z+1)^3$$

Comment: I added an update with the final step of my proof. Could you take a look and see whether it is sufficient? Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

In this case, I think a direct solution is easier than induction (though surely induction should work)

Index the formulas starting with $n=0$.  The $n^{th}$ left hand sum can be written as:  $$m(n)-n,m(n)-n+1,\cdots,m(n)-1, m(n),m(n)+1,\cdots, m(n)+n$$

for $m(n)=n^2+n+1$.

It follows that the sum of the terms in the $n^{th}$ sum is $$(2n+1)m(n)=(2n+1)(n^2+n+1)=2n^3+3n^2+3n+1$$

On the other hand the $n^{th}$ right hand is $$(n+1)^3+(n)^3=2n^3+3n^2+3n+1$$ and we are done.

Comment: Could you take a look at my update? Your input is highly appreciated.

Comment: @Cro-Magnon  The update looks good!